# "The required options you selected are not available." in cart in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart, bundled-product

Bundle option id is change every time,when i will any change like add some option or remove some option.Suppose I have one bundle product in cart before changes.After bundle product changes, Carts is showing error "The required options you selected are not available." in Magento-2.1. How to solve this error,Please help me this is major issue.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshots of your cart. so that way all can have a better idea?

Comment: https://imageshack.com/a/img924/5594/0DPDCk.png

Comment: Have you checked quantity and stock status of sub products which are associated with your bundle product?

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya Yes, I will check all sub products of bundle.All Products are instock and quantity is greater than 0.

Comment: Ok let me look at it I have a same problem in one of my websites

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya you find any solution?

Comment: No i haven't found it yet.

Comment: Please tell me any solution,it is a major issue.